# Unit tests failing "TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined" when using md-icon

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, svg, karma-jasmine, angular-material

I have an angular app (using AngularAMD/RequireJS) and I'm converting the design to use angular-material. I have a toolbar directive that has `md-icon` using `md-svg-src`.

Trouble running the `toolbar-directive_test.js` file.

At first it kept complaining "Unresolve GET request images/icon.svg". I resolved in the test setup using:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET(/\.svg$/).respond('');
```

Now if I run that test file using `fdescribe(...)` all the tests pass.

But if I run all my app tests (without `fdescribe` on that toolbar test file), they are somehow failing because of the md-icons. The error I get, which appears on another test file:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined
```

The stack-trace does not give any guidance on what is causing it. Only mentions `angular-mocks.js`, and then exits around the any random assertion on this test file where the error is showing. And if I `xdescribe` this file which is showing the `element of undefined` error, the next test file is failing with this error instead.

If I use `xdescribe` on `toolbar-directive_test.js` file (the one which has the `md-icon`), all the tests pass.

And if I run all tests including the `toolbar-directive_test.js` file, but I remove all the `md-icon` instances from its template, again all the tests are passing.

I have tried including `ngMaterial-mocks` package in my tests, and that doesn't do anything. But in general, I'm not using that package (but I am using `ngMocks`).

Any suggestions on how to debug this?

Comment: It's only a guess, but maybe `undefined` refers to the SVG itself. Try passing back `<svg></svg>` and see if it does anything different.

Comment: @Widget yeah that worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As @Widget suggested, **this works**:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET(/\.svg$/).respond('<svg></svg>');
```

Where this didn't work:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET(/\.svg$/).respond('');
```